# Internal Server Error joomla 1.5

Tags: .htaccess, joomla1.5, internal-server-error

Please help me in joomla 1.5.
I have Internal Server Error in my website, please give me right path that how to solve this.

error log:

```
/home/xxx/public_html/.htaccess: Option FollowSymLinks not allowed here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .htaccess file, try commenting the line:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

The error is probably because apache httpd main virtualhost configuration doesn't let you use `Options`.

Comment: Ok i will but i have one more problem that is i have htaccess.txt file not .htaccess file,is it a major problem.??:(

Comment: yes it is; don't touch it, it means you have other problems which are not solvable without (much) more informations

Comment: can you please help me how to fix this.?

Comment: i would but you need to provide a lot more detail in your configuration (os, webserver, logs, and so on)